# Mostrar un registro IONIC

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic, ionic-framework, console

Estoy intentando que al loguearse solo muestre un registro con el su respectivo id.
Llevo este codigo pero no me muestra nada tanto en consola como en la app.

```
this.authservice.getpet("users","uid").subscribe((resultado) => {
  // Preguntar si se hay encontrado un document con ese ID
  if(resultado.payload.data() != null) {
    this.petsA.uid = resultado.payload.id
    this.petsA.data = resultado.payload.data();
    // Como ejemplo, mostrar el título de la tarea en consola
    console.log(this.petsA.data.uid);
  } else {
    // No se ha encontrado un document con ese ID. Vaciar los datos que hubiera
    this.petsA.data = {} as PetInterface;
  } 
});
}
```

Y al momento de correr la app esto arroja:

Console:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

App:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pareciera que no estuviera extrayendo como es debido del Firebase.

Comment: Puedes mostrar como estas haciendo la consulta

Comment: Listo ya edite la pregunta, alli muestra la consulta

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo de la consulta de firebase